# Not able to use Query set for multiple databases in django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-database

I am able to use query set for default database.
But when I use query set for another database, throwing exception.

In my application I use two database.
sqlite and Mysql

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'abc.db',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    },
      'second' : {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'abc',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': 'abcdb',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': 'xxxxx',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
          }
}
```

when I use query set for first database it is not throwing any exception.
While using using second database it is throwing table is not available.

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /abc/xyz/

Caught DatabaseError while rendering: no such table: second.tablename

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/xxx/yyyy/?q=abcd
Django Version:     1.3.1
Exception Type:     TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    

Caught DatabaseError while rendering: no such table: second.tablename
```

Comment: are you sure that the table exists in the database?

Comment: Have you created a router (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#using-routers)? It's likely the table is only in one of the databases (rather than Django throwing up when trying to query).

Comment: database1 has different tables and database2 has different tables.

Comment: database1 has different tables and database2 has different tables.When I run the below command shell = db2models.tablename.objects.get(name='abc') throwing below exception DatabaseError: no such table: xyz

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the reply Tom,
I have tried second database manually and it worked for me.

```
   $model_seconddb.modelname.objects.using('seconddatabasename').filter(name='xxx')
```

This can be used when all the tables are not there in both the databases.

When you want to use default database, there is no requirement for using (using).
It will directly query from default database.

Answer (score 0):

The Best option to use multiple Database in Django is also use a routing to manage multiple DB, Here the documentation:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/multi-db/#topics-db-multi-db-routing

Here a full example from the Doc:

```
class AuthRouter(object):
"""
A router to control all database operations on models in the
auth application.
"""
def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
    """
    Attempts to read auth models go to auth_db.
    """
    if model._meta.app_label == 'auth':
        return 'auth_db'
    return None

def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
    """
    Attempts to write auth models go to auth_db.
    """
    if model._meta.app_label == 'auth':
        return 'auth_db'
    return None

def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
    """
    Allow relations if a model in the auth app is involved.
    """
    if obj1._meta.app_label == 'auth' or \
       obj2._meta.app_label == 'auth':
       return True
    return None

def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
    """
    Make sure the auth app only appears in the 'auth_db'
    database.
    """
    if app_label == 'auth':
        return db == 'auth_db'
    return None
```

Without specify the database in query, Django will use the right database in base of the table name.

Hope this help :)